# httpOnly cookie not getting sent with request from getInitialProps [Next.js]

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I am setting an `httpOnly` cookie (jwtToken) from the server and it is getting set on the frontend. I can see the cookie in devTools.

Now, if I make a request to the server from getInitalProps using the following code,

```
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/me`, {
    credentials: 'include',
  }).then((res) => res.json());
```

The `jwtToken` cookie is not sent with the request.

I tried doing this as well

```
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/me`, {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      cookie:  context.req.headers.cookie
    },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
```

but that didn't work as well.

However, when I make the same request from `useEffect`
it works perfectly. Can anyone please help me sending that `jwtToken`t o the server from`getInitialProps`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual problem was absence of the `jwtToken` cookie from `context.req.headers.cookie`. It would work on the localhost but not on production.

The solution to this problem is setting the `domain` on your cookie. So, if the frontend is on `example.com` and API server is on `api.exmaple.com` then setting the domain to `.example.com` would solve this issue.

`res.cookie('jwtToken', token, { httpOnly: true, domain: '.example.com'});`

Answer (score 2):

There is a-lot of confusion regarding when `getInitialProps` are called from.

There are 2 context which it get called from:

1. Server side, when initial page get rendered. that means that your client send the cookie in the request, and you need pass it forward to the the "server to server" request.
2. Client side, on the second page (client side nav). that means that the browser attaches the cookie to the ajax request.

```
Component.getInitailProps = async context => {
  const data = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/me`, {
    credentials: 'include', // tells the browser to attach cookies
    ...(context.req
      ? {
          headers: {
            Cookie: Object.entries(context.req.headers.cookie)
              .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
              .join('; '),
          },
        }
      : {}),
  }).then(res => res.json());
};
```

For server side, you need to pass a string, therefore, I'm constructing the cookie string using `Array.map`.

Comment: Hi @felixmosh! Thank you for your response. I tried this and it still doesn't work and the reason for that is the `jwtToken` cookie is not there in `context.req.headers.cookie` but it is there in browser devTools.  The real problem is the absence of `httpOnly` cookie from `context.req.headers.cookie`. Other non httpOnly cookies are present in context.

Comment: Can you specify on which side it not works for you, server it client (or both)?

Comment: for my case it worked but i had to change it to `Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie`, thank you @felixmosh